# Is there a packaged utility to manage users in ASP.NET's membership and roles system?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership, membership-provider

Is there a utility that will manually enter a new user in the ASP.NET membership and roles SQL tables? I'm looking for something that has a UI for making the necessary changes/insertions into the SQL tables.

I would like to find a packaged way to managing users/roles as simply as possible, without necessarily adding all this functionality to my app. My gut tells me there's some utility to manually do this from a command line or some other utility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a reference to the old, deprecated one (which I was sure existed), and I a link to a new one.

The old one was called "ASP.NET Website Administration Tool," and was removed in 2014.

An alternate is called Thinktecture.IdentityManager, and is on GitHub here:

https://github.com/IdentityManager/IdentityManager

Found via Scott Hanselman's post here:

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ThinktectureIdentityManagerAsAReplacementForTheASPNETWebSiteAdministrationTool.aspx